# Deserialize Json Object null value

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization

I'm getting some problems to deserialize a JSON object into my object, I'm getting some nullable values to determinated properties.

### The problem: Full object nullable

In this case I'm getting all my object properties null value.

Json example:

```json
{
 "message":{
    "ts": "11/10/13 15:07:16",
    "content": "vivo-2482573605"
 }
}
```

Code to make the request and return deserialized object:

```cs
public T Request<T>(IEndPoint jsonObject)
{
  string endPoint = jsonObject.ToURL();
  string requestType = jsonObject.RequestType;    
  string jsonData = jsonObject.Json;    
  HttpWebRequest request = initRequest(URL + endPoint, requestType);
    
  if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonData)){
    using (var writeStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
       writeStream.Write(jsonData);
    }
  }    
  try{
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();    
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
      string jsonResponse = streamReader.ReadToEnd();   
      if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(jsonResponse)){
        T value = Util.DeserializeJsonObject<T>(jsonResponse);
        return value;
      }    
      object ret = null;
      return (T) ret;
    }
  }catch (WebException we){
    object a = null;
    return (T) a;
  }catch (HttpResponseException hre){
    object a = null;
    return (T)a;
  }
}
```

Deserialize method:

```cs
public static T DeserializeJsonObject<T>(string json)
{
  T deserizadedJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<T>(json);
  return deserizadedJson;
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm getting my object With all properties null, I expect get this properties populated with the values in JSON object.

My object:

```cs
[DataContract]
class Message
{
   [DataMember]
   public string ts { get; set; }
    
   [DataMember]
   public string content { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: And `T` is the type, i.e. a class you constructed which matches the returned object? I recommend using http://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/

Comment: Can you clarify what the problem is.  Expected result vs actual result would help.

Comment: Instead of casting null, better return default(T)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just have to change my model, to json adapt it. Now i got this:

ResponseJsonPosition:

```
[DataContract]
class ResponseJsonPosicao
{    
    [DataMember]
    public Message message;
}
```

Message class:

```
[DataContract]
class Message
{
    [DataMember]
    public string ts { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string content { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you stumble across this in your search for an answer (as I've just done) it is worth checking your class for private setters and the absence of a parameterless constructor.

```
public string BusinessName { get; private set; }
public string Address1 { get; private set; }
public string Address2 { get; private set; }
```

In my case I have a domain layer with entities, which do not have parameterless constructors and all have private setters. The deserialiser, much like MVC's auto-binding, requires a parameterless constructor and public setters.

I created a stub class (locally) and deserialised into that, using it to build a call to my entity class constructor.

```
public class LookedUpAddress
    {
        public string Address1 { get; set; }
        //...


// Deserialise...
List<LookedUpAddress> addressListStub = serializer.Deserialize<List<LookedUpAddress>>(result);


// Use it to create the entity
foreach (LookedUpAddress addr in addressListStub)
                {
                    addressList.Add(
                        new Address(
                        addr.AddressLine1,
                        //...
```